# How to transform array to this json pattern?

Tags: php

I have array something like this

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 13
            [unit] => 1
            [price] => 20.0000
            [total] => 20.0000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 15
            [unit] => 2
            [price] => 30.0000
            [total] => 10.0000 
        )

)
```

I was stuck to transform above array to the "ProductList" in the following pattern

```
array(
     "UserID" => 2,
     "ProductList" => [
         {
             "ProductID"=> 13,
             "Price"=> 20.0000
         }, 
         {
             "ProductID"=> 15,
             "Price"=> 30.0000
         }
     ]
)
```

I tried like this:

```
$products = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    if(!empty($item['product_id'])) {
        $product = '{"ProductID"=>' . $item['product_id'] . '}';
        $products[] = $product;
    }
}
```

But not the expected result.

Comment: use the php provided `json_encode` function

Comment: What you want to transform to isn't really JSON with that outer `array()`.  What is it that you want, exactly?

Comment: @Brad I have array from the first block of code. Just wondered how to pass the values into "ProductList" of second block of code (Need exactly same pattern like this)
Failed with json_encode, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @Kuang First, get the structure you want in a regular object.  Then, use `json_encode()` on that object.  It's a two-step process since you want to transform that object first.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `json_encode()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Assign your array to a variable, for example `$products`, and then you can simply write `json_encode($products)` to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't usually all that useful.  While you're right, assume the person asking the question actually did look in the manual and probably doesn't know what they're looking for.  You don't have to write a book on the topic or anything, but some in-context code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$prodlist = array();
$x = 0;
foreach($arrs as $arr) {
    //if ($arr['product_id'] == "" && $arr['price'] == "") continue;
    $prodlist[$x]['Price'] = $arr['price'];
    $prodlist[$x]['ProductID'] = $arr['product_id'];
    $x += 1;
}
$arr2return['user_id'] = $user_id;
$arr2return['ProductList'] = $prodlist;
json_encode($arr2return);
```